# Error with array.h headers

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, g++, clion

I use CLion and I have this simple code:

```
#include <array>

int main() {

    std::array<std::uint64_t, 3> arr;
    return 0;
}
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I tried all the compiler flags from c++11/gnu++11 to c++17/gnu++17, but I keep getting this error when trying to build the code above

```
/pathToCLion/clion-2018.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build 

/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default --target my_project -- -j 2
/pathToCLion/clion-2018.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/pathToCLionProject/my_project -B/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 my_project
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
/pathToCLion/clion-2018.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/pathToCLionProject/my_project -B/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/pathToCLion/clion-2018.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles 2
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/all
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/depend
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
cd /pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default && /pathToCLion/clion-2018.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /pathToCLionProject/my_project /pathToCLionProject/my_project /pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default /pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default /pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target my_project
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/build
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/pathToCLionProject/my_project -I/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client -I/usr/local/include/pqxx -I/usr/pgsql-10/include  -pthread -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp.o -c /pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:9:10: error: ‘array’ is not a member of ‘std’
     std::array<std::uint64_t, 3> arr;
          ^~~~~
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:9:10: note: ‘std::array’ is defined in header ‘<array>’; did you forget to ‘#include <array>’?
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:6:1:
+#include <array>

/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:9:10:
     std::array<std::uint64_t, 3> arr;
          ^~~~~
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:9:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
     std::array<std::uint64_t, 3> arr;
                             ^
/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp:9:34: error: ‘arr’ was not declared in this scope
     std::array<std::uint64_t, 3> arr;
                                  ^~~
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/dev/hmmenc_client/test.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:71: CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/pathToCLionProject/my_project/cmake-build-default'
gmake: *** [Makefile:121: my_project] Error 2
```

This is my g++ version: gcc version 8.1.1 20180502 (Red Hat 8.1.1-1) (GCC). What can cause this error?

Comment: I'm curious why this question got a down vote. (I just upvoted to bring it back to 0.) The OP is giving us a minimal example, the error message is wicked complicated, and the solution (if the answer is correct) would take many of us a long time to figure out on our own. What's the complaint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if you have an empty file named `array` in any of the directories listed on the include path (`/pathToCLionProject/my_project`, `/pathToCLionProject/my_project/dev/hmmenc_client` `/usr/local/include/pqxx`, `/usr/pgsql-10/include`).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I found a non-empty file named `array` in my `/usr/local/include/pqxx` path that caused the problem. At the end it was my fault, I shouldn't have included the `/pqxx` in my path to work with the package.